# Android galaxy s20+ brightness keeps resetting every 5 minutes

Tags: brightness, samsung-galaxy, screen-brightness

I have an android galaxy s20+ with the app Twilight installed.  The screen brightness and dimming seemed to work fine up until a few days ago.  Now at night when the brightness is usually set to nearly off (just a sliver showing on the bar, maybe ~5%), the brightness will continually change/reset to ~20-25% every ~5 minutes, almost to the second.  It does this with Adaptive Brightness on or off.  It might also be happening more throughout the day, but I only noticed at night when the Twilight app is active and my screen is dimmed to only about 5%.  Aside from the Adaptive Brightness, I'm not sure what other apps or configs might be affecting this.  Help?

Comment: This question appears to be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow, where the focus is on specific software/programming problems. It is possible that your question is a better fit for the [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) site - but first check their [help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and look at questions which have been well received there (and those which have been poorly received). Also do plenty of research on that site, in case this question has already been asked.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem in the last few days with my Samsung Galaxy A52s, especially during the day, indoors, when the phone screen would suddenly get brighter for no reason. I kept trying to fix it by turning adaptive brightness on or off. Today I uninstalled Twilight and the problem seems to be fixed. (I assume an upgrade conflicted with Twilight?) At night I'm using Eye Comfort Shield in the phone settings, not as good as Twilight but ok.